# Easy methods of installing and having access to the GDAL library?

Tags: installation, libraries, gdal, qgis

The GDAL library homepage implies that people who arrive there already know what they are doing.  I work with ArcGIS, and am unfamiliar with intricate setups with library dependencies as GDAL suggests. Is there an easy "package" i can download?  I have found maptools.org, and i guess the libraries that has is accessible by any programming language of choice? I also found QGIS which apparently uses GDAL.

I am looking into GDAL because it has functionality that ArcGIS does not. My language of choice is python. What is my best (and easieist) route to take here??

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest option is probably to use the OSGeo4W (for Windows) installer. With this you can select GDAL from a large list of OpenSource GIS tools. Under "libs" select the version of GDAL you want. To add Python support select gdal**-python making sure the versions match. You can uncheck anything else (except I think you need Python-numpy which is selected by default):

http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/

Then  check out some of the sample Python / GDAL scripts at:

http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/samples/

More GDAL Python details here:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/

**Other Options**

Take a look at http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries

You can run the set up package in the zip here (there doesn't seem to be a 1.7 version out yet):

http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/win32/1.6/gdalwin32exe160.zip

A smaller collection of tools can be found here (FW is for Frank Warmerdam the creator/maintainer of GDAL):

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FWTools

Comment: OSGeo4w is the preferred route on Windows. FWTools is de-emphasized and is mainly supported out of consideration for those who have become accustomed to it and are not ready to change. It is possible to [http://yukongis.ca/How_To/Shared_ArcGIS_and_Osgeo4W_python_install share a single python install between arcgis and o4w], but to begin with it is simpler to keep the two in parallel and ignorant of each other.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add a ready-made GIS to your python/GDAL code, Quantum GIS (Qgis) has an embedded python interpreter and a full python API. You can write plugins for Qgis in python, and use GDAL functions for raster data. Qgis is in the osgeo4w system.

Answer (score 2):

**Download:**

- Get Python 2.4 from http://python.org/ftp/python/2.6.6/python-2.6.6.msi
- Get the GDAL Python bindings from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL
- Get GDAL from http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/win32/1.6/gdalwin32exe160.zip
- Get PROJ4 from http://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj446_win32_bin.zip

**Installation:**

1. Run the Python installer to install python
2. Unzip the GDAL archive and place it in c:\gdal-1.6
3. Add a GDAL_DATA user variable with containing the full path to the data folder "C:\gdal32-1.6\data" (Control Panel > System Properties > Advanced tab > Environment Variables)
4. Append "C:\gdal32-1.6\bin" to your system path
5. Unzip the PROJ4 archive and place it in c:\PROJ
6. Append "C:\PROJ\bin" to your system path
7. Unzip the GDAL Python bindings and copy the osgeo folder to "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages"
8. You might need to append "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages" to your system path.

**Testing:**
Open IDLE and type

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

I have found these instructions useful, but not entirely applicable or up to date: http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/docs/gdal_win.pdf. Note that a newer version of GDAL is available (1.7.3), but needs to be compiled from source and that no windows executable exists yet. Version 1.6 contains a few very serious bugs.